# How do you insulate exposed crawl space?

Tags: insulation

How do you insulate floor of cabin built on piers that has exposed crawl space and also keep the mice out? I want to insulate floor from underneath cabin. Cabin is in northeast U.S. and subjected to winter weather.Floor Joists are 24" oc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fill the joist bays with fiberglass or mineral wool batts, then you cover the underside of the joists and batts with a few inches of rigid foam or rigid mineral wool boards, and then you protect that layer by covering it up with plywood or OSB. One layer has to be your air barrier. If you use rigid foam, make that your air barrier and caulk and tape the seams. If you use rigid mineral wool, the plywood will be your air barrier so caulk and tape the seams. I think mice would be hard pressed to chew through plywood from the bottom while crawling up piers, but if they can, protect the piers themselves with downward-facing anti-mouse cones made of metal or something.

Comment: Closed cell spray foam will also give you a moisture barrier as well. That could be used in place of the batts and rigid foam setup.

Comment: True, but it would be more expensive and provide less insulation if you only sprayed between the joists (which would leave thermal bridging) or make it awkward to apply the protective plywood (if you fully encapsulated all the joists with spray foam). It would also be more of a fire hazard and have worse environmental impact due to the not-so-green aerosols involved.

Comment: Also, you don't really want a moisture barrier on your floor in a case like this. If there's a spill that wets your wooden subfloor, and it can't drain due to a bunch of spray foam clinging to the underside of the subfloor, it's gonna rot that wood.

Comment: Thanks to iLikeDirt. Going w your suggestion. Will use Roxul 24" Mineral Wool Batts (fire proof),poly foam & OSB.I agree mousies would have a hard time.Thanks for your expertise.  P.Pine

Comment: Glad to help. One thing: I hope "poly foam" means "polystyrene foam (EPS, XPS, or maybe polyiso)" and not "a layer of poly sheeting and foam." You don't need or want any poly sheeting here.

Comment: Roger that,should have typed extruded polystyrene.I have wondered if I could use a house wrap for air barrier in place of EPS. That could save some $.I will not use spray foam (cost,fire haz,t.bridge) or create a  moisture barrier.More Thanks to iLikeDirt. P.Pine

Comment: Housewrap isn't an air barrier unless you tape off all the seams, and can collect liquid moisture. The foam covering the underside of the floor joists is there to mitigate their thermal bridging as well as to be an air barrier. FYI extruded polystyrene (the pink or blue stuff) is XPS; EPS is expanded polystyrene (white stuff; used for packing materials). EPS is a lot cheaper, better for the environment, and doesn't expand and contract as much as XPS; if you're not space-limited, I'd recommend EPS instead.

Comment: Roger,EPS it is. Im fortunate that I have 40" to work under cabin.Tks 4 clarification .Im good to go.P.Pine